# Как получить доступ к коду html?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите с решением вопроса. Как возможно через js получить весь код html включая всех потомков элемента(div)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите сюда

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

либо

```
document.getElementById("root").innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("div").innerHTML` - так не работает.

Comment: не работает если нет такого элемента в документе

Comment: Нет, никогда, не будет работать - `getElementsByTagName` возвращает коллекцию.

Comment: спасибо, исправил